# Iphone: how to launch a route in google maps api from your application

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have read a lot of topics, but i don't find when i want

I want to launch google map api from my application with that:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=41.029598,28.972985&daddr=41.033586,28.984546"]]
```

But it's open safari with Google maps page. I want open Google map API with my route. There is a maps:// or other things?

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: Are you testing on simulator? if yes, try on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=41.029598,28.972985&daddr=41.033586,28.984546"];

    [app openURL:url];

    [url release];
```

Comment: it's exactly what he does, but with one difference: your code is leaking ;)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Apple URL Scheme Reference for MapLinks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)

Edit: your URL looks correct. Looks like you are testing on Simulator! GoogleMaps app is only available on device!

Comment: There are better here:http://mapki.com/index.php?title=Google_Map_Parameters#Output_Control

Comment: see my edit ;). and you need to use the apple schemes, because google maps app doesnt support all parameters which the webapp is supporting

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?&saddr=%@ &daddr=%@",sourceaddress,destinationaddress];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
```